# How to understand this SDE?

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, notation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In a paper I'm reading appears the following SDE:

$$\mathrm{d}u=\omega u^\perp\mathrm{d}t+(\sqrt{2d}\circ\mathrm{d}B_t)\cdot u^\perp u^\perp $$

here $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $\omega:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $d$ is a real number, $B$ a two-dimensional standard Brownian motion, "$\cdot$" is the standard scalar product and for $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$ the vector $x^\perp$ is defined by $x^\perp=\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\-x_1\end{pmatrix}$. I don't understand what this SDE looks like in integral notation. It should start like

$$ \begin{pmatrix}u_1(t)\\u_2(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u_1(0)\\u_2(0)\end{pmatrix}+\int_0^t\omega(s)\begin{pmatrix}u_2(s)\\-u_1(s)\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{d}s+.....$$

How is the stochastic part defined here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sqrt{2d} \circ dB_t$ is this some Ito or Stratonovich product?

Comment: the circle should denote the Stratonovich integral.

Comment: How can a deterministic function $u$ be a solution to a Stratonvich SDE? This doesn't make sense...

Comment: Oh ...$u:\Omega\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a stochastic process with values in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of course

Comment: You are making the stratonovich product agains the constant $\sqrt{2d}$? this should have an explicit form in terms of the Brownian motion....
 What is the meaning of $u^\perp u^\perp$?

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Nowhere in the paper is stated how this should be understood, they just state this SDE with barely no explanation

Comment: What is the paper?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1953 page 11

Comment: are you thinking about eq (2.15) in page 11? if not, then could you point out the display of the eq you are interested in?

Comment: yes exactly this equation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46727/discussion-between-conrado-costa-and-lukas-benedikt-fiechtner).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.1953.pdf, the typo in 2.15 was fixed to

$$\mathrm{d}u=\omega u^\perp\mathrm{d}t+(\sqrt{2d}\circ\mathrm{d}B_t)\cdot u^\perp  $$

for $u^{\perp}=(u_{2},-u_{1})$ and $B=(B_{1},B_{2})$

$$=\omega \binom{u_{2}}{-u_1}\mathrm{d}t+2d\binom{u_{2}\circ dB_{1}}{-u_1\circ dB_{1}} $$

and so as noted here [Conversion between solution to Stratonovich SDE and Itô SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296945/conversion-between-solution-to-stratonovich-sde-and-it%C3%B4-sde)

$$=(\omega+\frac{1}{2}) \binom{u_{2}}{-u_1}\mathrm{d}t+2d\binom{u_{2}dB_{1}}{-u_1 dB_{1}}. $$