# Conversion between solution to Stratonovich SDE and Itô SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

We start with the SDE
$$\frac{dX}{dt}= h(X)+\gamma(X)\circ \frac{dW}{dt}.$$

By looking at [the formula to convert between Stratonovich and Itô integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratonovich_integral#Comparison_with_the_It.C3.B4_integral), it seems to me that a solution to the above should also satisfy the Itô SDE

$$\frac{dX}{dt}= h(X)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial\gamma(X)}{\partial W} +\gamma(X) \frac{dW}{dt}.$$

However, the notes I'm looking at write this last equation as

$$\frac{dX}{dt}= h(X)+\frac{1}{2}\nabla.(\gamma(X)\gamma(X)^T)-\frac{1}{2}\gamma(X)\nabla.(\gamma(X)^T) +\gamma(X) \frac{dW}{dt}.$$

Are they the same? If so, how can I see this equivalence?

Comment: Are you only one person? I am asking because the three questions "you" asked since this one are at a level so different (so much more elementary) from the present one that one finds oneself at a loss to imagine any answer to the present question which would be useful to the author of the three others. (And, as usual, offering a bounty is no substitute to the structural problems, if any, with a question.)

Comment: Hi Did - first, yes, I am one person. Admittedly I should have put more effort into answering my last questions before posting them, I can see your point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are considering the Stratonovich SDE
$$ dX = h(X) \, dt + \gamma (X) \circ dW, $$
where I suppose the following hold:

1. $h \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$,
2. $\gamma = (\gamma_{ij})_{i,j = 1}^{n,m} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $,
3. $W$ is an $m$-dimensional Brownian motion.

Such a SDE is equivalent to the Itô SDE
$$ dX = \left( h(X) + \frac{1}{2} c(X) \right) dt + \gamma (X) \, dW, \tag{1} \label{1}$$
where $c = (c_i)_{i=1}^n \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by
$$ c_i (x) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial \gamma_{ik}}{\partial x_j} (x) \, \gamma_{jk} (x).$$
In order to obtain \eqref{1}, apply exactly the conversion formula that you can find, e.g., at page 123 of the book *An introduction to stochastic differential equations* by Lawrence Evans.

I hope that this can help to clarify what the notes you are looking at do, but perhaps you have to give some more details about the functions appearing into the SDE.

Comment: I think that's page 123. Either way - thanks! That was exactly was I was looking for. It took me a while, but what Evans gives is exactly what my notes give, it was just a matter of expanding out that the terms completely and everything ended up matching.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Page 123, sorry :) I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to fill in the details, in case this turns out being useful to anyone.

To save space, I'll write $\gamma_{ij}$ instead of $\gamma_{ij}(x)$.

$$\left(\nabla.(\gamma\gamma^T)\right)_{i} = \sum_{l,j}\frac{\partial(\gamma_{ik}\gamma_{jk})}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{k,j}\frac{\partial(\gamma_{ik})}{\partial x_j}\gamma_{jk}+\sum_{k,j}\frac{\partial(\gamma_{jk})}{\partial x_j}\gamma_{ik}=c_i + \left(\gamma\nabla.(\gamma^T)\right)_i.$$

Rearranging, this shows that the answer provided by @mTur11 matches that provided by the notes I was referring to.

Comment: I really think you should change $\gamma\,\nabla \cdot (\gamma^T)$ to $\gamma\,\nabla \cdot \gamma$